# What would be an appropriate DIN rail mounted relay to allow a residential switch from one power supply active 5 circuits from another power supply

Tags: relay

In my house there is a switch controlling 30 or so outdoor garden lights. The problem is that should one light get damp, it will trip the fuse taking out all the lights. It is also hard to troubleshoot which light is causing the issue.

I have recently had a second supply installed in the garden shed and now have all the lights on grouped together in batches of 5 or 6, each batch on a separate circuit. If one light trips the fuse it only takes out another 4 or 5 lights and hence also easier to troubleshoot.

But the one switch is still in the house and I can't run extra wires from the house to the shed as the wiring is embedded in walls etc and not accessible so I only have one on / off switch wired from the house to the shed.  Is there a relay type device that could be mounted in the distribution board that when the switch is activated in the house, it switches on multiple lighting circuits in the shed? I have been trying to find a suitable product online for ages but no luck.  I hope the attached diagram helps.[image: Garden Lighting]

Comment: It is not clear if you want to switch all lights on (since you have only few existing wires) or group by group - since each group has a separate relay as depicted.

Comment: The switch currently switches all lights on and thats what I’d still like to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFNjjB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could use just one contactor for all ligts.

[image]

Or this one, with remote switch yet installed from different source.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Thanks. What is this product ? A contactor?

Comment: @Ben DIN rail modulsar contactor.

Comment: Thank you. I see you mention only one is required but I'm not clear on how it can control all 5 lighting circuits. Given each lighting circuit is on its own circuit breaker, is that a practical solution?